# Auto accept EULA in bash script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, installation, eula

I'm trying to write a bash script that (among other things) installs *ubuntu-restricted-extras*, but I can't seem to find a proper solution to automatically accept the EULA. This has been suggested in another post:

```
yes | apt-get install -y ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

But this is not working for me. Any ideas?

Comment: You want `debconf-set-selections`.

Comment: When you say, `But this is not working for me`, what exactly do you mean? What errors are you seeing?

Comment: @Inian mean that when I call the script from the terminal, the EULA still appears.